# Residues/Power Series

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Use the fact $e^z = -1$ when $z = (2n+1) \pi \imath$ to show that $e^{1/z}$ assumes the values $-1$ an infinite number of times in each neighborhood of the origin. More precisely, show that $e^{1/z} = -1$ when $z = - \frac{\imath}{(2n+1)\pi}$ then note that if $n$ is large enough, such points lie in any given $\epsilon$ neighborhood of the origin.

I tried to expand $e^{1/z}$ into its power series. Then I substitued $z$ with $- \frac{\imath}{(2n+1)\pi}$. However, I still ended up with a series that didn't give me $-1$ as the first term, which I assume it should right?

Comment: Please include in your question what you have already done.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what your problem is and why in the world would you want to use the power series of $\;e^z\;$ for...Just *substitute* $\;\frac1{(2n+1)\pi i}\;$ in $\;e^{1/z}\;$ ! you don't even need that weird minus sign there...